# Account-base package on Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have to deploy now my app and I was wondering to my self if is a good idea bring apps to production with the account-base package. Wouldn't be better to manage this with our own methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is create as many fields as I want and onCreateUser get them and save this on my ddbb
More info: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser

Answer (score 2):

I think trying to manage it all yourself is a sure fire way to run into problems in the future. The concept of accounts seems simple, but the implementation never is especially when you start sprinkling in all the extra complexities (registration, resetting passwords, validation emails, 3rd party authentication, role based authorization, complete integration with your app, etc.).

At the end of the day, you dont gain much by spending days (or more) implementing and testing (hoping that you got everything right) that stuff when you could be spending​ that time on building the next big app.  I'd much rather use tried and try packages that have verified by thousands of users across thousands of apps instead of trying to roll my own.

Comment: that's true, but one thing is a package to manage notifications or the splash screen which is "not relevant" but other thing is manage your user creation and login with a third party package. It's true that you'll need to create the bbdd, methods, tests, etc. but it think it's a must when you're working in any important app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your purposes and preferences. Since `account-base` seems to fit well on my projects, I recommend you to get the most out of it and don't waste your time *reinvent the wheel*.

However, in the scope of `meteor`, if you want to make changes to the package, you can clone it to the `packages` directory and modify it your way.

Comment: I agree with that. Sometimes we try to create everything by ourselves but as I said above there are some quite of few important things like register/login which would be more specific for our apps. E.g. I need to create an user with username and email (not only one of them) and I think from this point is more difficult to archive this with the account-base package than create everything by my self. And also I'd need to send to client a code to translate the message on my location file